# Using double setListAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Can I use this?

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ListViewActivity.this, menuItems,
    R.layout.list_item_projects,
    new String[]{KEY_JOBTITLE, KEY_JOBINFO}, new int[]{
    R.id.jobtitle, R.id.jobinfo});

ListAdapter taskadapter = new SimpleAdapter(ListViewActivity.this,menuItems,
    R.layout.list_item_tasks,
    new String[]{KEY_TITLE,KEY_INFO,KEY_OBJECT,KEY_LOCATION},
    new int[]{R.id.title,R.id.info,R.id.object,R.id.location});

setListAdapter(taskadapter);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

or can I just use one `setListAdapter`?

Comment: use only one. You can take a look at Merge Adapter by commonsware https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge

Answer (score 0):

u can't use twice setListAdapter just once